# SELECT on a condition - help!

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables with a username and email. I'm writing a php script which includes SQL that checks if a submitted username and/or email is taken.

I only want the column(s) returned if the username, email or both is taken otherwise I want nothing selected.

Is this possible?

cheers,